# Spring calling properties file correctly

Tags: java, spring, properties, message

I have a spring mvc application and I am rendering some pdfs using classes that extend AbstractPdfView.  I have several pdfs and I thought it would make sense to create a helper class to put some common functionality.  I then decided I wanted to add any output text to my messages_en.properties file.  How do I access this file from my helper class?  Right now I am creating an instance of my helper class manually. Looks like this:

```
   public class PdfEarningsRecordView extends AbstractPdfView {

    @Override
    protected void buildPdfDocument(Map<String, Object> model, Document document, PdfWriter writer, 
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        HelperClass helper = new HelpderClass();
......
```

I tried having the Helper extend ApplicationContextAware but always returned null.  I also tried the following with the same result:

```
@Autowire
private ApplicationContext context;
header = context.getMessage("myHeader", null, Locale.getDefault());
```

I feel like I am not using Spring correctly when creating the HelperClass manually as well.  Any tips would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AbstractPdfView` is a subclass of `ApplicationObjectSupport`, which has a useful `getMessageSourceAccessor()` method, which returns a `MessageSourceAccessor`, which is the easiest way to get messages from the framework.  Just pass that to your helper class:

```
public class PdfEarningsRecordView extends AbstractPdfView {

@Override
protected void buildPdfDocument(Map<String, Object> model, Document document, PdfWriter writer, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    HelperClass helper = new HelperClass(getMessageSourceAccessor());
```

The helper can then use that accordingly.

Note that in order for this to work, the `PdfEarningsRecordView` object must be properly initialized. Spring will generally do this for you, by calling its `ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext()` during startup, but if you instantiate a `PdfEarningsRecordView` yourself, for whatever reason, you'll have to call that method yourself.